# using git in phpstorm do i need to commit to see changes?

Tags: css, git, magento

I am new to git and new to phpstorm so this may be stupid, but, I am working on a css file for a magento site, I have git enabled and all files are added to the repository (they are all green).

I made some changes to the css file, but when I refresh the site which I am running locally, no changes show.

Do I need to commit the changes everytime? I know when I commit a change I get the dialog box asking for comment etc. This seems kind of slow when dealing with css as I often want to just save the file quickly, and refresh the page to see if everything works as predicted.

Or am I understanding git wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to commit changes. Your problem is probably cache. Browser or magento cache for css files. Try to refresh with Ctrl + F5